# Latest match data game center

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, game-center-leaderboard, gkturnbasedmatch

As I am working on a turn based game using game center. All is working fine like sending turn to next player, skip turn, quit match and all. The only problem is that I am not getting the **latest match data** until or unless user doesn't clicks on **notifications** sent via Game Center. Suppose some one send me the turn with some data, and I got the notification but user didn't click on the notification. In this case User are not getting the latest match or match data. Please provide me some solution about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but do you call this method before the data is used?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKTurnBasedMatch/loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler: